# IDEA: Opening file in right-hand split with search anywhere

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I have a vertically split window and I bring up "Search Anywhere" (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>) to jump to a new file, the file always appears in the left-hand split, even if my cursor is in the right-hand split.

How do I get the new file to open in the right-hand split?

Note that I'm using IdeaVim and I'm creating the initial vertical split by typing `:vsp`.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if you have solved the problem. E.g. having the same :(

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the right pane via right-click: *Split Vertically*, it works.

There must be an issue with `:vsp`.

(IDEA v14.0.2)